# vue component complains about import

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm writing a vue component NavItem that represents am Item in a Navigation. I also have a NavItemModel class written in TS. But when I try to import it, vue complains that the module is not found:

Project structure

```
vue
./src
...../components
...../components/NavItem.vue
...../models
...../models/NavItemModel.ts
```

NavItem.vue

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <a href="">{{content.title}}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {NavItemModel}  from "../models/NavItemModel";
export default{
    name: 'NavItem',
    props:{
        content: NavItemModel
    },
    components:{
        
    }
}
</script>
```

NavItemModel.ts

```ts
export class NavItemModel{
    title:String;
    link: String;
    parentItem:NavItemModel;
    childItem:NavItemModel;
    constructor(title:String,link:String,parentItem:NavItemModel,childItem:NavItemModel){
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.parentItem = parentItem;
        this.childItem = childItem;
    }
}
```

[image: vue error]
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your webpack config?

Comment: @Terry I don't have a webpack config. I used the vui ui to initialize the project

Comment: What's VUI? Do you mean Vue CLI?

Comment: @Terry jep i meant vue ui. the ui tool for the vue cli

Comment: Did you initialize your project using Vue CLI with TypeScript enabled? If not, you can simply update your Vue CLI project by doing `vue create /your/folder/path`, or simply create a new project and copy the files over (but at the risk of losing your git commit history)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set typescript language `<script lang='ts'>`
2. Declare your property like

   ```
    props: {
     content: Object as () => NavItemModel
    }
   ```

Comment: A correct type is `PropType<NavItemModel>`. It's not a function

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: 11:24  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: <script lang='ts'> already solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your app folder structure right:
/src
/src/models

you should import it like:

```
import {NavItemModel}  from "@/models/NavItemModel";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not destructure the class. Destructing is used for properties and functions

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <a href="">{{content.title}}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import NavItemModel  from "../models/NavItemModel";
export default{
    name: 'NavItem',
    props:{
        content: NavItemModel
    },
    components:{
        
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It needs to be destructured because OP is not using `export default class`, but using a named export instead.